# Where/how are categories stored?

Tags: categories, command-line

Disclaimer: I am new to WordPress.

When I add categories to my blogging site, where/how are these categories stored?  If I want to change the names of these categories in batch, without having to go through the point-and-click UI, how would I go about it?  Would this be done through a command-line interface?

Comment: check prefix_terms and prefix_termmeta table in your database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is extensive documentation on [the database structure of WordPress in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).
Its pretty simple but still you probably do not want to mess with the data directly.

As you mentioned CLI I'd recommend [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) which offers some commands you need. A quick example from the docs to change the name of the `term` with the `ID` `15` from the taxonomy `category` to `Apple:

```
wp term update category 15 --name=Apple
```

Comment: So, I shouldn't go into the database.  Is management from the command-line an accepted methodology? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. WP-CLI is the new hotness

Comment: @jgraup Thanks so much.  Another question recommends using it through Composer on Windows.